# What does the sentence "chart induces coordinates" really mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $Q$ be a smooth $n$-manifold and let $(U,\varphi)$ a chart for $Q$. What does "$\varphi$ induces local coordinates $(q^1,...,q^n)$? I supposed $\varphi=(q^1,...,q^n)$, i.e. $$\forall x\in Q, \quad \varphi(x)=(q^1(x),...,q^n(x))\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
but it seems to be wrong.

The real question cames form the Tangent bundle $\tau_Q:TQ\rightarrow Q$ and cotangent bundle $\pi_Q:T^*Q\rightarrow Q$.

In the first case the chart $(\bar{U},\Phi)$, induced by $(U,\varphi)$ as $\bar{U}:=\tau_Q^{-1}(U)$ and
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Phi:\bar{U}&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^{2n}\\
V& \mapsto &(\bar{q}^1(V),...,\bar{q}^n(V),dq^1(V),...,dq^n(V)),
\end{array}
\end{equation}
with $\bar{q}^i:=q^i\circ\tau_Q$.

Then I would say that $\Phi$ induces local coordinates $(\bar{q}^1,...,\bar{q}^n,dq^1,...,dq^n)$, but in literature i found the induces coordinates are $(q^1,...,q^n,\dot{q}^1,...,\dot{q}^n)$. Can someone explain why $q^j$ instead of $q^j\circ \tau_Q$? Or how are defined those $\dot{q}^i$ and their relationship between $dq^i$?

For the cotangent bundle define the chart chart $(\tilde{U},\psi)$, induced by $(U,\varphi)$ as $\tilde{U}:=\pi_Q^{-1}(U)$ and
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\psi:\tilde{U}&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^{2n}\\
m& \mapsto &(\tilde{q}^1(m),...,\tilde{q}^n(m),p_1(m),...,p_n(m)).
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Thus I would say that $(\tilde{U},\psi)$ induces local coordinates $(\tilde{q}^1,..,\tilde{q}^n,p_1,...,p_n)$, and this is the case I found in literature too. But I does it seem not to work in the tangent bundle? Are somehow different the definitions of coordinated in tangent and cotangent bundle? 
Any answer would be useful, Thank you.

Comment: For your first question: yes, the induced local coordinates are indeed $q^i=P_i\circ\varphi$ where $P_i:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is the $i$th projection, so that $\varphi(x)=(q^1(x), \dots, q^n(x))$.

Comment: For your second question: the notation $q^i$ in the tangent bundle is indeed sloppy and it can only be meant as $q^i \circ\tau_Q$. For your 3rd question, what are $p_i$?

Comment: \begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
p_i:M&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
m&\mapsto&m\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}|_{\pi_Q(m)}\right),
\end{array}
\end{equation}
then we can write $m=p_i(m)dq^i|_{\pi_Q(m)}$. @Berci